# Why does the login window become active after sleep?

Tags: macbook-pro, sleep-wake, login-screen

I'll put my MacBook Pro (13" with Touchbar) to sleep and walk away. When I return, more often than not, the login window is active on the display. Why?

My first thought was notifications. Nope. There are no notifications on screen. Next, I thought that maybe some USB peripheral (hard drive, mouse, etc.) was waking it up. I unplugged my Time Machine drive and my mouse/keyboard dongle. Nope. Still wakes up. Last was my external monitors. No luck there either. The only thing plugged in now is power.

After sleeping the Mac, I'm not sure how long it takes for it to wake back up. Sometimes I'm away for 15 mins, sometimes overnight.

I'm guessing there's some software reason why the Mac is waking up. What's going on here… and more importantly, how do I prevent it?

---

Here's why I care: I have two old and inefficient external displays attached. When the machine wakes up, it lights 'em all up. That's a waste of power and unnecessary usage. I'd like to keep these monitors around as long as I can.

Comment: Are you certain it's actually asleep? I've seen apps that can keep it awake & you end up with an odd kind of hybrid screen-saver plus login screen at the same time. Check Activity Monitor, right click any of the headers & add "Preventing Sleep", click that header to sort any Yes to the top.

Comment: @Tetsujin I did not know that Activity Monitor trick. Nice! Anyway, I did that. The only things preventing sleep are system level (sharingd, hidd, SpringBoard). And yes, the Mac is definitely fully asleep initially.

Comment: OK, it's very unlikely to be hidd unless it's gone rogue. Not so sure about sharingd, mine shows as No, even with inbound & outbound shared folders to other Mac & PCs. I've never used Launchpad so idk how that should show.

Comment: Have you looked at the "Power Nap" feature under the "Energy Saver" setting ?? https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204032

Comment: @ReneLarsen Power Nap is on… but isn't the whole point that it does all of its stuff while the Mac is asleep? I guess I could try turning it off temporarily.

Comment: @Tetsujin By Launchpad, do you mean SpringBoard? I just figured out that SpringBoard is only a thing when the iOS Simulator is running (for iOS development). It happened to be running when I checked Activity Monitor. It's normally not running.

Comment: @Sam As you also can read in the link I posted - it depend on which power the mac is using. On battery it will not wake up to much, but on AC it will wake up and do stuff all the time.

Comment: @ReneLarsen Right. So are you saying that when the Mac is doing its Power Nap routines, it lights up the login window? Can you confirm? I would have assumed that, even when Power Nap is doing its thing, it would be in the background and the displays would be dark.

Comment: SpringBoard was the original name for Launchpad; I'd assumed it may still show that as a background process name. Didn't really check it out too carefully, sorry.

Comment: @ReneLarsen I also noticed that "Wake for Wi-Fi network access" is on too. I don't have any other computers on the network that are doing anything like file sharing… but could this have something to do with it?

Comment: @Sam I don't know, I'we always disabled Power Nap, I just know it will wake up the mac, but don't know about the screen. The only way to find out what all the setting under "Energy Saver" are doing, is to try then out.